# How to debug the following as an extension author: Extension host terminated unexpectedly. Code: 3221225477 Signal: null

Tags: visual-studio-code

My VSCode extension is causing the extension host to terminate unexpectedly (happens after waking the computer from sleep).

How can I debug this issue? There are no additional logs before or after the `Extension host terminated unexpectedly. Code: 3221225477 Signal: null` entry in the console and debugging with an exception breakpoint doesn't help either as the Extension Host is terminated.

Is there some setting or flag I can enable to get additional logging for crashes such as this?

Answer (score -1):

It seems 3221225477 shown in HEX is 0xC0000005 which is a STATUS_ACCESS_VIOLATION code on Windows.

https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/wiki/Native-Crash-Issues#windows